# Is it possible to set memory use for javapackager?

Tags: java

IS it possible to setup for example at least 2GB for my javafx application to be used when packaging with javapackager? JRE default anyone know that?

Possible to set heapsize ?

Comment: You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting the `jvmOptions` accordingly

> `jvmOptions=option`
>
> Option to be passed to the JVM when the application is run. Any option that is valid for the java command can be used. To pass more than one option, use multiple instances of the -B option[..]

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/javapackager.html

```
-BjvmOptions=-Xmx2g
```

Would set the the heap limit to 2GB. Documentation of available options can be found in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html#BABHDABI

Comment: Thanks, do you know the default value for heap size?

Comment: @Mikael the default value is calculated dynamically by the JVM. You can print which options your jvm decided to use when you don't specify it like http://marxsoftware.blogspot.de/2011/01/hotspot-jvm-options-displayed.html . But that limit might be different for someone else. The JVM is intended to be smart enough to do the right thing. If your application is known to need 2G, then set that, otherwise letting the JVM choose is fine.